# How does the replace function of a string work in JavaScript when passing a function as its second argument

Tags: javascript

```
camelize = function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(/\W+(.)/g, function(match, chr) {
    return chr.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

What is in the argument match and char, which is passed to replace function as second parameter. I could not understand what is in it.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Is there something we can cover which [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) does not?

Comment: The first argument is the whole match, the remaining arguments are the matches for each capture group. It's not complicated.

Comment: So `chr` gets the character matched by `(.)`

Comment: Read The Friendly Manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: Thank you all for sharing documentation links..